# How do you call a mutator from within a constructor in the same class?

Tags: java

For a homework assignment the instructions state (within Undergrad class):

*You do NOT need to include a default constructor, but you must write a full parameterized constructor (it takes 4 arguments) -- this constructor calls the parent class parameterized constructor and the mutator for year level.*

Because Undergrad extends Student, then Student is my parent class, right? I just can't quite figure out how I'm to use my year level mutator (which is just the simplest of methods) to assign my "year" attribute.

```
    public void setYear(int inYear)
{
    year = inYear;
}
```

---

```
public Student(String inName, String inID, int inCredits)
{
    name = inName;
    id = inID;
    credits = inCredits;
}
```

---

```
    public Undergrad(String inName, String inID, int inCredits,int inYear)
{
    super(inName, inID, inCredits);
    year = inYear;
}
```

I keep missing assignments because I spend too much time on these small specific points of the homework so just asking for a little help. I swear it's the wording that throws me off on these assignments almost as often as just learning the material itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe they want you to use the setter in order to set the year instead of setting the year directly.

```
public Undergrad(String inName, String inID, int inCredits,int inYear)
{
    super(inName, inID, inCredits);
    setYear(inYear);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I thought I had try doing that, albeit I don't remember and wasn't positive at all on my syntax. It compiles now though so I'll continue my assignment and hope the rest goes unhitched(without a hitch? Couldn't not being hitched be bad depending on perspective of the hitch, such as being on the passenger car when a train uncouples/unhitches from its powering engine cab in front?)

Anyways, thank you very much for the prompt response.